# Why doesn't sed 's/\r\n/\r/g' work as expected?

Tags: sed, line-endings

In normal windows-to-unix conversion, you can do something like `sed s/\r//g`, which removes the \r characters from the stream.

But I'm trying to convert endlines of files that could be mac encoded (\r) or windows encoded (\r\n). So I cannot just remove the \r, as it would delete the mac endings if there's any. I have to "canonicalize" the line-ending characters first. This canonicalization step converts from \r\n to \r (after which I do the \r to \n conversion). Yet, I'm not able to solve this step with `sed`. I tried something like this:

```
$> echo -e "foo\r\nbar" | sed 's/\r\n/\r/g' | xxd -c 24 -g 1
00000000: 66 6f 6f 0d 0a 62 61 72 0a            foo..bar.
```

I was able to solve it with bbe like this:

```
$> echo -e "foo\r\nbar" | bbe -e 's/\r\n/\r/g' | xxd -c 24 -g 1
00000000: 66 6f 6f 0d 62 61 72 0a               foo.bar.
```

Is it possible to do the same with sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` by default splits input on `\n`, so `\n` never ends up in the pattern space. However, if you are using **GNU `sed`**, you can use [`-z`/`--null-data`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dz) option to make `sed` treat the input as `NUL` character separated lines:

```
$ echo -e "foo\r\nbar" | sed -z 's/\r\n/\r/g' | hd
00000000  66 6f 6f 0d 62 61 72 0a                           |foo.bar.|
```

Alternatively, in **POSIX `sed`**, you can append all lines to the pattern space (with [`N` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_03) in a loop), effectively copying the complete file to the pattern space, and then do the substitute:

```
$ echo -e "foo\r\nbar" | sed -n ':a;N;ta; s/\r\n/\r/g; p' | hd
00000000  66 6f 6f 0d 62 61 72 0a                           |foo.bar.|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl` which doesn't remove the record separator unlike sed/awk. This solution doesn't require entire file to be slurped

```
$ echo -e 'foo\r\nbar' | perl -pe 's/\r\n/\r/' | xxd -c 24 -g 1
00000000: 66 6f 6f 0d 62 61 72 0a                foo.bar.
```

Note that `g` modifier is not needed as `\n` can occur only once per record